# How to set Intent parameters to display more layout details?

Tags: android

I can use the following code to display a image in system layout.
Can I customize the system function buttons displayed or not in the system layout?
I find the system buttons in layout for view image is different when I open system Gallery app.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id = v.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,ForBrowse);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it depends on what app is handling the intent.  That's actually configurable by the OEM and the user.  There's no way to guarantee that any parameter that one app will take will be handled by another.  Remember that you aren't just showing a layout-  you're launching a separate application.